# NW extension - multiple graphs with nw:generate?

Tags: netlogo

I want to build several random subgraphs in one world. As, in general, the number of subgraphs is not fixed, I don't want to use different breeds for each subgraph. So far I use a pretty rude approach (see below) with "handmade" random networks, assingning a "my-group" variable to the turtles. I am new to the NW extension and I wonder if it would be possible to create several subgraphs using the nw:generate-random module without using breeds for each subgraph.
Do you have any suggestions?
Thanks, Hannah

```
to create-subgroups
  crt network_size [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]
  let group-n 0
  repeat network_size / group_size [ ;; group_size is always a factor of network_size
    ask turtles with [who >= (group-n * group_size) and who < ((group-n + 1) * group_size)] [
      set my-group group-n           ;; get group number
      repeat (random 4) + 1 [        ;; create links
        let target one-of other turtles with [who >= (group-n * group_size) and who < ((group-n + 1) * group_size)]
        if target != nobody [
          create-group-link-with target ] ] ]
    set group-n group-n + 1 ]
end
```

Comment: The way you have it, each turtle must be connected to at least 1 other turtle, but might be connected to all other turtles in the subgraph. Is that what you want? There are many common ways of generating random graphs. Are you particular? `nw:generate-random` may help in your situation, but it only says "each of these turtles has such and such probability of being connected"; it does not guarantee that turtles will have at least one link for instance. Is that acceptable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question! This should be a nicer way of generating the same graphs that you're currently generating:

```
to create-subgroups
  repeat network_size / group_size [
    let group (turtle-set)
    crt group_size [ set group (turtle-set group self) ]
    ask group [
      create-group-links-with n-of (1 + random 4) other group
    ]
  ]
end
```

This assumes that group_size is greater than 4 (otherwise there may not be enough turtles in the group to link to).

The idea here is that rather than keeping track of who's in the group with `who` numbers, you can can use a turtle-set. Besides being cleaner, it allows you to store the groups in a list for later reference. So if you have a global `groups` that you've set to a list, you can add the groups to it like so:

```
to create-subgroups
  repeat network_size / group_size [
    let group (turtle-set)
    crt group_size [ set group (turtle-set group self) ]
    ask group [
      create-group-links-with n-of (1 + random 4) other group
    ]
    set groups (lput group groups)
  ]
end
```

Update:

You can use a similar technique with `nw:generate-random`. `nw:generate-random` generates an subgraph, it won't take over your whole network. The turtles and links will be whatever breed you specify, but they will only connect to other turtles in breeds being currently created by `nw:generate-random`. Thus, this should work:

```
to create-subgroups
  repeat network_size / group_size [
    nw:generate-random turtles links group_size connection-probability
  ]
end
```

where `connection-probability` is the probability that any two turtles in the newly created subgraph will be connected. You can still snag references to the newly created turtles to store in a list in a similar way as above:

```
to create-subgroups
  let group (turtle-set)
  repeat network_size / group_size [
    nw:generate-random turtles links group_size connection-probability [
      set group (turtle-set group self)
    ]
  ]
  set groups (lput group groups)
end
```

This way, you've got turtle-sets for each of the components, the number of components is completely variable and changeable in a behavior space run, and the components are completely disconnected from each other.

Comment: Hello Brian, thank you for your answer, that seems already better than what I did. My problem with the understanding of nw:generate-random is the following: I do not know how to generate, say 4, disconnected graphs without using brees for the single graphs. I want to change the number of graphs during BehaviorSpace, for that I don't want to use breeds. As for your comment: a connection probability would be acceptable; in fact, I would prefer this.

Comment: Update my answer to use `nw:generate-random`!

Comment: Tiny point: I recently [learned from Seth](https://github.com/NetLogo/NW-Extension/issues/125#issuecomment-47670289) that building an agentset with successive calls to `turtle-set` is O(n2). Something like:
`let group-list []
crt group_size [ set group-list fput self group-list ]
let group turtle-set group-list`
would be faster.